# How to edit style (font color) of dojo.TitlePane programatically

Tags: dojo

I have a TitlePane which I want to change the font color. I just cant. I need to do this programatically.

So far I have something like this:

```
var newPane = new TitlePane({title: paneName});
```

I have tried this as well:

```
var newPane = new TitlePane({title: paneName, id: paneName, style:{color:'red'}});
```

This sets the content of the pane red and no id is added anywhere :(

As per this [API info](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/TitlePane.html#dijit-titlepane) I can only set three properties (title, content and open). How could I add an id and style(color) to the TitlePane! pls

Answer (score 1):

Style it via Cascading Style Sheets. See how it works at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/63dHY/

To change the color of `TitlePane` title text by `id`

```
var titlePane1 = new TitlePane({
    id: "titlePane1",
    title: "some red title",
    content: "Collapse me!"            
}, "titlePane1");
```

use the following style:

```
#titlePane1 .dijitTitlePaneTextNode {
    color: red;
}
```

Or by `class`

```
var titlePane2 = new TitlePane({
    title: "some blue title",
    content: "Collapse me!"
}, "titlePane2");

domClass.add(titlePane2.domNode, "blue");   // as of 'dojo/dom-class' module
```

use the following style:

```
.blue .dijitTitlePaneTextNode {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

​
or change it directly via JavaScript (which I do not recommend):

```
titlePane2.titleNode.style.color = "green";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newPane.style({color: "red"});
```

OR

```
query(newPane).style({color: "red"});
```

OR

```
newPane.style.color = "red";
```